# Getting values from JSON hash

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa, core-data

I'm stuck with this JSON which I have to load into Core Data:

```
{
  "versions": {
          "group12": "2662ad279e1c4303b534a0f363be7b90",
          "group51": "2205e48de5f93c784733ffcca841d2b5",
          "place123": "856babf68edfd13e2fd019df330e11c5"
      } 
}
```

I don't know how should I cope with this in `forin` loop. For now I have some code which is only showing me the name of the version e.g. `group12`, `group51` but I can't get those hashes from this JSON...

```
for (id activity in [responseObject objectForKey:@"versions"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", activity);
}
```

Probably this will be some very basic stuff but my mind today is a little bit outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get back a `NSDictionary *` from `[responseObject objectForKey:@"versions"]`. If you use fast enumeration over an dictionary, you'll only get the keys. But if you want the key and the value use

```
[[responseObject objectForKey:@"versions"]
    enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop){
  // do something with key & object
}]
```

If you know, you'll always have `NSString *` objects in your dictionary, you can specialize the parameters' types. Although this won't change anything during code generation, it'll give you a better code completion and warnings/errors, if you try to use methods on the key or the object `NSString` doesn't implement.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently logging only the key from the dict,

get the object for that key too

```
for (id activity in responseObject[@"versions"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", activity); // key
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject[@"versions"][activity]); // value

}
```